# Neo4j: Java heap space error after query exectuion with create unique statement

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, heap-memory

I am trying to test some queries on some neo4j databases, different in the amount of data. If I test that queries on small amount of data, everything goes right and execution time is small, but when I start execute queries on database with 2794 nodes and 94863 relations, It will take a long time to get following error in Neo4j API: 
**Java heap space  Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownFailure**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSFOG.png)
First query:

```
    MATCH (u1:User)-[r1:Rated]->(m:Movie)<-[r2:Rated]-(u2:User)
WITH 1.0*SUM(r1.Rate)/count(r1) as pX, 
1.0*SUM(r2.Rate)/count(r2) as pY, u1, u2
MATCH (u1:User)-[r1:Rated]->(m:Movie)<-[r2:Rated]-(u2:User)
WITH SUM((r1.Rate-pX)*(r2.Rate-pY)) as pomProm,
SQRT(SUM((r1.Rate-pX)^2)) as sumX, 
SQRT(SUM((r2.Rate-pY)^2)) as sumY, pX,pY,u1,u2
CREATE UNIQUE (u1)-[s:SIMILARITY1]-(u2)
SET s.value = pomProm / (sumX * sumY)
```

And second query

```
    MATCH (u1:User)-[r1:Rated]->(m:Movie)<-[r2:Rated]-(u2:User)
WITH SUM(r1.Rate * r2.Rate) AS pomProm,
SQRT(REDUCE(r1Pom = 0, i IN COLLECT(r1.Rate) | r1Pom + toInt(i^2))) AS r1V,
SQRT(REDUCE(r2Pom = 0, j IN COLLECT(r2.Rate) | r2Pom + toInt(j^2))) AS r2V,
u1, u2
CREATE UNIQUE (u1)-[s:SIMILARITY2]-(u2)
SET s.value = pomProm / (r1V * r2V)
```

Data in database are generated from following Java code:

```
public enum Labels implements Label {
    Movie, User
}

public enum RelationshipLabels implements RelationshipType {
    Rated
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, BiffException {
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/DP/dvdlist.xls"));
    Workbook names = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/DP/names.xls"));
    String path = new String("C:/Users/User/Documents/Neo4j/test7.graphDatabase");
    GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(path);
    int countMovies = 0;
    int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
    IndexDefinition indexDefinition;
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
        Schema schema = db.schema();
        indexDefinition = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label(Labels.Movie.toString()))
                .on("Name")
                .create();
        tx.success();
    }
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
        Schema schema = db.schema();
        indexDefinition = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label(Labels.Movie.toString()))
                .on("Genre")
                .create();
        tx.success();
    }
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
        Schema schema = db.schema();
        indexDefinition = schema.indexFor(DynamicLabel.label(Labels.User.toString()))
                .on("Name")
                .create();
        tx.success();
    }
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(i);
            int numberOfRows = 6000;//sheet.getRows();
            for (int j = 1; j < numberOfRows; j++) {
                Cell cell1 = sheet.getCell(0, j);
                Cell cell2 = sheet.getCell(9, j);
                Node movie = db.createNode(Labels.Movie);
                movie.setProperty("Name", cell1.getContents());
                movie.setProperty("Genre", cell2.getContents());

                countMovies++;

            }

        }
        tx.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something goes wrong!");
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    int countUsers = 0;
    Sheet sheetNames = names.getSheet(0);
    Cell cell;
    Node user;

    int numberOfUsers = 1500;//sheetNames.getRows();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
        cell = sheetNames.getCell(0, i);
        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
            user = db.createNode(Labels.User);
            user.setProperty("Name", cell.getContents());
            List<Integer> listForUser = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
                int j = random.nextInt(countMovies);
                if (!listForUser.isEmpty()) {
                    if (!listForUser.contains(j)) {
                        listForUser.add(j);
                    }
                } else {
                    listForUser.add(j);
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < listForUser.size(); j++) {
                Node movies = db.getNodeById(listForUser.get(j));
                int rate = 0;

                rate = random.nextInt(10) + 1;

                Relationship relationship = user.createRelationshipTo(movies, RelationshipLabels.Rated);
                relationship.setProperty("Rate", rate);

            }
            System.out.println("Number of user: " + countUsers);
            tx.success();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something goes wrong!");
        }
        countUsers++;
    }

    workbook.close();
}
```

}

Does anyone know, how to solve this issue? Or there is some walkaround, how to get results from that queries on a database with a large amount of data? Or some query or settings improvement? I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to configure the amount of memory available to Neo4j. You can configure Neo4j server heap size by editing `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`:

```
wrapper.java.maxmemory=NUMBER_OF_MB_HERE
```

See [this page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/performance-guide.html#_configuring_heap_size_and_garbage_collection) for more info.

However, looking at your queries (which are doing graph global all-pairs operations) you might want to consider doing them in batches. For example:

```
// Find users with overlapping movie ratings
MATCH (u1:User)-[:RATED]->(:Movie)<-[:RATED]-(u2:User)
// only for users whose similarity has not yet been calculated
WHERE NOT exists((u1)-[:SIMILARITY]-(u2))
// consider only up to 50 pairs of users
WITH u1, u2 LIMIT 50
// compute similarity metric and set SIMILARITY relationship with coef
...
```

Then execute this query repeatedly until you have computed the similarity metric for all users with overlapping movie ratings.

Comment: Thanks, memory really helped me. And I will try your second advice.

Comment: I am trying your code, is there a way, how loop this query in cypher?

Comment: Not in Cypher, but in the client just check for results in a `while (results)` type loop

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (in version 4.1) and the properties could be found in `conf/neo4j.conf` or select active database -> Manage -> Settings and increase:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size
dbms.memory.heap.max_size
```

More details about performance could be found in [documentation](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/)